# Removed Desktop by rm Desktop and now desktop connects Home instead

Tags: 16.04, directory

So i had this problem where i had a file called Desktop but it was not my desktop file, that i needed to remove, and so I did. Before doing that,i did `mv Desktop Defwp` this, then i deleted with `rm Desktop`. It worked fine, but when i restart my comp, in my desktop, there was files in Home repository.

I changed Defwp to Desktop, in Home, yet still in desktop there are files in Home folder.

How to get files in Desktop to my desktop?